# Selection based on 1st, 2nd, 3rd ... choice

Tags: algorithm, vote

I am looking for an algorithm that can automate the selection of final-year projects for students:

Students (`n`) are offered projects (at least `n`) and make a 1st, 2nd, 3rd, j ... choice. The projects are then assigned based on these choices. Manually, I first try to match all 1st choices, then 2nd choices etc - but the results depend a lot on intuition and often could be improved. Hence, I would like to use/create an algorithm that can do this automatically.

Is there any such algorithm available which I seem to miss?

Thank you!

Comment: Is exactly one student assigned to each project?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Comment: This can also be translated into a conventional linear programming by creating a boolean variable for each student being assigned to each project. We know that each student should be assigned to exactly one project and that each project should have at most one student assigned to it. Thus, the sum of some subsets of these boolean variables will be exactly 1 and the sum of other subsets will be less than 1. Once this is done, an objective function can be written and something like the simplex method can be employed.

Comment: It is one student per project (but there might be more students than projects). The problems are ties and how to resolve them: the first choice should be assigned in a way that those who did not get their first choice should get their second etc - apart from building trees, I can't see an easy solution here.

Comment: read the link I posted above, or https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Comment: Thank you - this was very helpful and I found `matchingMarkets` for R which seems to implement the algorithm